# When entered into Google, what's the difference between "link:www.mysite.com" and "links:www.mysite.com"?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, backlinks

I've heard this is the way to measure inbound links to a website?  What is the difference between the two and is there a better way besides these?

Comment: Did you learn about these in the *same* place, or is it just that you've run across both across various articles, etc.? (A link might help with evaluating the rest of my comment.) There's something odd here. `links` is consistently giving me more results, but `link` is the actually *documented* operator. I can't immediately see what the difference is, and if the extras are valid, though. For the time being, I would trust the `link:` results more if only because it's what you're "supposed" to be using.

Comment: Ignore previous comment. See edit to my answer for follow-up.

Answer (score 7):

links: is not a Google Search operator, so it is equivalent to just use the word link as an additional keyword in the search. The proper operator to use is link:, not plural.

Answer (score 4):

> I've heard this is the way to measure inbound links to a website?

It's **a** way to get a feel for it.
Arguably Google would prefer that you do it via their [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), where you'll find it under [Traffic->Links to Your Site](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55281). The `link:` operator only shows you a selection of results like `site:` does. (Mentioned at that previous link.) Webmaster Tools is also a better option for this as it provides some extra information like who links to you most, and *how* your site gets linked to.

Note that if you do continue using the `link:` operator, Google [recommend](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35256) using the domain name without the www sub-domain. (They're [not the same thing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/what-does-www-do).)

**[EDIT]**
On further review using a domain I control and so could do a better job filtering, it looks like non-existent search operators, eg `links:` just get ignored and treated as a literal strings as much as possible. It'd be nice if they popped a warning message about this. But for example, if you do a search for "[foo:rottentomatoes.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=foo%3Arottentomatose.com)" you'll see results up top for things like the movie "To Wong Foo…" and the actor John Foo, plus even attempts to figure out if your search was a typo, eg. "Kung **Fu** Panda" also shows up.